# The client has been inactive... Stopping the connection

Tags: signalr

I use ASP.NET & SignalR. Normally the SignalR run smoothly, but sometimes it is disconnected from the server and show this error.
"The client has been inactive since Mon Jul 19 2021 19:31:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) and it has exceeded the inactivity timeout of 50000 ms. Stopping the connection."
Do you know why?
Furthermore, I use this code to reconnect, but it said $.connection is undefined

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
           $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000);
    });
```

How can I restart the connection?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using v2.4.2 or an older version?

Comment: hi @FrankMk, I use v2.4.1

Comment: Trying bumping up to 2.4.2. They made an update to deal with a change in Chrome/Edge that would disconnect clients after a period of time when not in focus. Not sure if that will fix your error without more details.

Comment: thanks @FrankM. Will try

Comment: Depending on what happened, SignalR may or may not disconnect you. At times, it will just keep your old connection and reconnect you. If that's the case, then your $.connection.hub.disconnected callback will not fire.